# Struggling to extract regular expression group match

Tags: powershell

I set myself a "PowerShell challenge" modeled after the [LINQPad challenge](http://www.linqpad.net/Challenge.aspx) and am stumbling early and frequently.

I'm trying to write a simple script to pull TargetFrameworkVersion elements from project files in Visual Studio solutions in order to confirm that the projects are consistently using a single version of the framework. The element matches the following in which X.Y={2.0,3.0,4.0,4.5}

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>vX.Y</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

I got this far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj | Select-String -Pattern "<TargetFrameworkVersion>(?<version>v[2-4].[05])</TargetFrameworkVersion" | ForEach {$_.Matches}
```

Thanks in large part to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7363134/609290) answer from ryant but stumbling as to how to grab the "version" group match. The results appear to be correct to this point:

```
Groups   : {<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion, v4.0}
Success  : True
Captures : {<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion}
Index    : 4
Length   : 52
Value    : <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion
```

But my attempts to grab "version" (or get closer to it) are failing:

```
$_.Matches["version"]
$_.Matches.Groups
$_.Matches | Select-Object Groups
```

My question is **How can I grab the "version" match group?**

I tried what I thought was a simpler variant and this works as expected:

```
"<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>" -match "<TargetFrameworkVersion>(?<version>v[2-4].[05])</TargetFrameworkVersion>"
$Matches["version"]
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I took EBGreen's advice (Thanks!) and had a whirl with XML/XPath. With stej's [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493554/609290), I was successful:

```
$ns = @(defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj | Select-Xml -xpath '//defaultNamespace:PropertyGroup/defaultNamespace:TargetFrameworkVersion' -namespace $ns | Select-Object -expand Node
```

**I would still like to understand what I'm doing wrong in the RegEx code** when using non-XML files.

Comment: If the file you are working with is valid XMLs, then using regexes is doing it wrong. Look at the [xml] type accelerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET regex object model uses collections of collections. Modify your final Foreach to:

```
... | Foreach {$_.Matches | Foreach {$_.Groups["version"].Value}}
```

BTW I agree with EBGreen, you want to use XML for this.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with EBGreen and Keith on using XML

```
$xml = get-content "myproj.vcxproj"
(([xml]$xml).Project.PropertyGroup | ? {$_.Label -eq 'Globals'}).TargetFrameworkVersion
```